# UIGestureRecognizer and derivates. How to "active" it on same moment of the tap?

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer

At first, take a look in my code.
I have some different codes, changing only the UIGesture, like tap, pan, long... and all gestures.
Just for test
 **Heres one**:

```
public class ....{    
    ...
       public override void ViewDidLoad ()
       {            
           Image1.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
           UIGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UIGestureRecognizer (TapThat);
           dot1.AddGestureRecognizer (tapGesture);
       }
    ....

       public void TapThat(){
       //Do some action...
       }
    }
```

**Another:**

```
public class ....{    
    ...

       public override void ViewDidLoad ()
       {            
           Image1.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

           UITapGestureRecognizer panGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer ((pg) => {
           //Do some action...
           });

           dot1.AddGestureRecognizer (panGesture);
       }
    ....

    }
```

This is two examples, but is missing some thing. I use the .State variable to get UIGestureState.
When I tap the image and keep the finger without moving, nothing happens. But if I tap and drag it's change.

**Just when I drag** , the state come on log:
State - **Began**.

If I **keep moving**:
State - **changed**.

When I **release**:
State - **Ended**.

What I need is in the exactly moment I tap the image, it's change to another image. Without drag, like a button.

It's clear?

This for IOS;

Comment: Use Began action if you want immediate feedback.

Comment: But the state began come after I tap the image and move the finger. It wasn't work.